# Little Math-help for image resize needed

Tags: image, math

I have an Image with the Value X width and Y height.

Now I want to set the height ever to 60px.

With which calculation I can calculate the height that the image is correct resized?

Comment: I guess my answer was too math-y, maybe? :P

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure that it was understandable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are trying to maintain aspect ratio. If so use the following:

ratio = orginialHeight / newHeight

newWidth = orginialWidth * ratio

Answer (score 8):

I assume you want the width after the rescale to relate to the height in the same way it did before the rescale, i.e. you want the [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio) to remain constant.

```
aspect_ratio = width_old / height_old
```

This gives:

```
aspect_ratio = width_new / height_new
```

Thus

```
width_new = width_old * height_new / height_old
```

Which means

```
width_new = (60 * width_old) / height_old
```

For instance, assume an incoming image of 640x480 (plain old VGA). This has an `aspect_ratio` of 1.33333...

Rescaling this to be 60 pixels high would then require a new width of 60 * 640 / 480, or 80, which seems proper since 80/60 is indeed 1.3333...

Comment: Given I'm not 100% sure I understand the intent of the question, but I think the OP wants to ADD 60 px to the original height, not multiply it by 60.  Also, I've nearly always heard/used the term as "aspect ratio", not just "aspect".

Comment: @PTBNL: My solution doesn't add, it sets the height to 60.

Comment: @unwind:  Sorry, I mis-read your answer the first time; indeed you do set the height to 60.

Answer (score 0):

You want to maintain an aspect ratio of `y/x`, which means that you need to compute `y/x` for the original image. Let `z = y/x`, then, given any new height `y'` (in your case, 60 px), to find the new width `x'`:

```
y/x = z = y'/x'

x' = y' * z
```