# Draw an image with a relative size to Panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, position, 2d

I know how to draw an image with java (with the paintComponent method) but I have a problem:
When I resize the frame, the image stays at the same size, but I want it to increase its size when I increase the size of the frame, and decrease its size when I decrease the size of the frame.

My code:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    g.drawImage(myImage, x, y, myWidth, myHeight, null);

}
```

I'm sure that I need to use the getWidth and getHeight method of the JPanel class, but I don't know the maths that I need to do.

Comment: You need to choose how much you want the image to be in relative terms (like 80% of frame width), then [scale it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729887/little-math-help-for-image-resize-needed).

Comment: override getPreferredSize for JPanel, tons examples here and in SSCCE /MCVE form

Comment: `I'm sure that I need to use the getWidth and getHeight method of the JPanel class` - Correct, so do it. Just change your code to use those method. Also you should be using "this" instead of "null" for the last parameter of the drawImage(...) method.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone, I'll try that later

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this code in paintComponents, you could put in a JFrame's overriden paint method.

That way when you resize the window, the paint method is called and and the image is resized.